# Can I throttle the max CPU usage of a php script?

Tags: php, cpu-usage

I have some scripts that use a ton of cpu is it possible to cap the amount of cpu a process is allowed to use? I am running on CentOs 5.5 by the way.

Comment: Do you mean in the php code itself?  You may be able to limit the php scripting engine through the OS but that wouldn't be programming related

Answer (score 10, accepted):

maybe you could use [nice](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nice_(Unix))?

Answer (score 11):

I helped a fellow PHP coder create PHP scripts which address a similar issue. These are long-running PHP scripts which generate a lot of load. Since they're long running, the goal was to "pause" them if load gets too high. The script has a function similar to:

```
function get_server_load()
{
    $fh = fopen('/proc/loadavg', 'r')
    $data = fread($fh, 6);
    fclose($fh);
    $load_avg = explode(" ", $data);
    return floatval(trim($load_avg[0]));
}
```

The script calls `get_server_load()` during each loop, and if the load is greater than a given max, it sleeps for 30 seconds and checks again:

```
set_time_limit(120);
while(get_server_load() > $max_load)
    sleep($load_sleep_time);
```

This allows the script to give CPU time back to the server during periods of high load.

Comment: This is nice approach, but note that you are returning int, not float, so you can't get load average of 0.9 eg.

Answer (score -3):

PHP is considered a scripting language, and does not have such low level access to the hardware.

Instead, what you can do is use functions like "set_time_limit()"

http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php

and memory_limit in your php.ini

http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php

Those are the recommended methods, but the closest you'll get to what you want are probably a combination of "sleep()"

http://php.net/manual/en/function.sleep.php

and getting the current CPU load with "exec('uptime');". Note that you may or may not have access to those system commands.

Comment: The load average is available in /proc/loadavg under linux. It doesn't require low level access to the hardware, it's a function of the operating system.

Comment: With this approach you will only _abort_ a script, not pause or limit it's cpu consumption.